# R14(Memory quota exceeded error ) on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I have standard 1x dyno on heroku for Rails Application.
I have set puma web concurrency as 1 by using command

```
heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
```

Here is my heroku logs

```
00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=68101pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24085pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2020-07-19T16:17:27.965465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.175619374.bf5929f5-5290-4852-803b-a191eec97d98 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2020-07-19T16:17:27.990534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.175619374.bf5929f5-5290-4852-803b-a191eec97d98 sample#memory_total=981.11MB sample#memory_rss=511.95MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=469.16MB sample#memory_pgpgin=1789258pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1658199pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2020-07-19T16:17:27.993885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=981M(191.6%)
2020-07-19T16:17:27.996828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2020-07-19T16:17:29.457018+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.175619374.ca710d80-bc87-4452-9750-e74d6e94eb24 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2020-07-19T16:17:29.476208+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.175619374.ca710d80-bc87-4452-9750-e74d6e94eb24 sample#memory_total=618.61MB sample#memory_rss=511.93MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=106.68MB sample#memory_pgpgin=208265pages sample#memory_pgpgout=77210pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2020-07-19T16:17:29.479858+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process running mem=618M(120.8%)
2020-07-19T16:17:29.481659+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2020-07-19T16:17:41.505992+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.175619374.01e9ad15-b8a6-46fd-bfa0-f6240896bfa0 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.03 sample#load_avg_15m=0.02
2020-07-19T16:17:41.531873+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.175619374.01e9ad15-b8a6-46fd-bfa0-f6240896bfa0 sample#memory_total=164.21MB sample#memory_rss=164.20MB sample#memory_cache=0.02MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=66123pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24084pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2020-07-19T16:17:46.270340+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: source=worker.2 dyno=heroku.175619374.c415ed03-9d64-49d5-b399-00e0b9d9d12e sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.00
2020-07-19T16:17:46.289815+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: source=worker.2 dyno=heroku.175619374.c415ed03-9d64-49d5-b399-00e0b9d9d12e sample#memory_total=171.94MB sample#memory_rss=171.94MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=68101pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24085pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2020-07-19T16:17:47.854476+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.175619374.
```

My gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'graphlient'
gem 'redis', '4.1.4'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'
gem "figaro"
gem "fog-aws"
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
```

Initially I was using hobby dyno but I was getting the same issue so I shifted to standard1x but still the same.
I am using heroku redis as redis_cache_store in my rails application.

Comment: Sorry, but do you have a question?

Comment: Why I am getting this issue??

Comment: @anothermh , I am not able to fix this, so can you please help me in telling me the issue

Comment: There is absolutely no way of knowing why you are getting this issue from the information presented in this post.

Comment: @anothermh what else I should share?

Comment: I recommend doing standard troubleshooting by creating a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

R14(Memory quota exceeded error) indicates that your application is using too much memory than it should.

From your post above it's hard to determine what causes the error.
There are several cases that cause the R14(Memory quota exceeded error) on Heroku.
One of them is memory leaks. In my previous experience, this error happens because I have unfinished loops in one of my files. I think you should check whether your application not experiencing memory leak.